# I can't get my head round - (void)playInputClick;

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have an inputAccessoryView for a UITextField set up, which is loaded from a XIB when needed (in the exact same way as Apple's KeyboardAccessory example).

I'm trying to get the buttons on it to click when pressed using the playInputClick function but I can't work out how. The [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIDevice/playInputClick) says that I need to add add a delegate method to the view, but the view was created purely in interface builder so I don't see how I can do this.

Does anyone know how to make this work? There seems to be no example code of this method being used anywhere on the internet.

Comment: you need to change the class to be a subclass of what it currently is and implement the protocol in the custom class

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are trying to do this in an inputAccessoryView:

In the `.h` file, indicate that you implement the `UIInputViewAudioFeedback`

```
@interface YourAcessoryView : UIView <UIInputViewAudioFeedback>
```

In the `.m` file, add this method to satisfy the protocol

```
- (BOOL)enableInputClicksWhenVisible {
    return YES;
}
```

When a button is pressed, do something like:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] playInputClick];
    // do more stuff
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've been having the same problem and finally figured it out.

If you implement the protocol in a UIViewController it does not work.  It needs to be implemented in a UIView subclass.

So to get it working, I created a view in interface builder with a view controller.  Then I added another class which is a subclass of UIView.  This class implements the UIInputViewAudioFeedback protocol.  Then in interface builder I went to the Identity inspector of my view and changed the class to my UIView subclass which implements the UIInputViewAudioFeedback protocol.  And the keyboard click sound is now working.

My view controller is still calling the `[[UIDevice currentDevice] playInputClick]`, all I did was move the code for the UIInputViewAudioFeedback protocol into a UIView Subclass and set my views class to my UIView sublass.

Comment: Thank you for most useful answer. So basically the method is useless for adding clicks to buttons on standard views. It all has to be subclassed.

Comment: @YiminRong seems he changed view of view controller with to own subclassed.

Comment: Provide my experience of making "Select collectionViewCell to playInputClick": implement UIInputViewAudioFeedback protocol in UICollectionViewCell subclass would not work. It has to be implemented in UICollectionView subclass.

Comment: Also check this answer here for an example implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39385287/1306012

Answer (score -2):

You need to implement a view controller class, and in the interface builder assign the files'owner as this class. Connect the view controller's view to your view.

Once you have done that you can implement the delegate in the view controller.
Its pretty simple and straight forward. Basically your view will be a member of a view controller class.

Comment: From the apple docs: 'Implement this protocol in your custom subclass of UIView'. So that's wrong, it's actually meant to be implemented in a UIViewController subclass instead?

Comment: You can create a custom class derived from a uiview too. Basically its the same.

Comment: OK, I've tried this. I've created a CustomKeyboardController class which implements the protocol and delegate method, the inputAccessoryView is set to customKeyboardController.view. When a button is pressed there is still no sound. I know the [[UIDevice currentDevice] playInputClick] method is being run as I have a NSLog statement next to it which I see debug output from. It's just that there's no sound.

Comment: Use this method to play the standard system keyboard click in response to a user tapping in a custom input or keyboard accessory view. A click plays only if the user has enabled keyboard clicks in Settings > Sounds, and only if the input view is itself enabled and visible. -- Have you checked the settings?

Comment: I have, the normal keyboard underneath the custom view does click.

Comment: Have you implemented enableInputClicksWhenVisible?

Comment: Yes, in the CustomKeyboardController class.

Comment: Any progress on this question ?? I have a custom class extending UIView CLass implementing UIInputViewAudioFeedback protocol, enableInputClicksWhenVisible return YES; i have tried with NO also  [UIDevice currentDevice] playInputClick] is also reached, but i don't hear any sound ? rest keyboard works fine, i have keys in  my inputAccessoryView ?