# "Plays Sound" Property of UIButton in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, interface-builder

in interface builder there is property of UIButton under Accessibility that says "Plays Sound".

Can any one explain what is this. Actually i am making an application which play sound on every button click and i can disable sounds from setting screen. Will this property of UIButton can help me?

Thanks

Comment: If you just need the keyboard click sound on button click, you can use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] playInputClick];`.

Comment: Yes exactly i need to play only a click sound. I added this line on button action and tested in simulator but no sound was played.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] playInputClick];` to play the keyboard input click sound which is available in `UIDevice`. Check this [apple documentation for more details.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIDevice/playInputClick)

You need to do the following for this,

1. Adopt the `UIInputViewAudioFeedback` protocol in your input view class.
2. Implement the `enableInputClicksWhenVisible` delegate method to return YES.

Do this in `UIView` class,

```
@interface MyView : UIView <UIInputViewAudioFeedback>
```

Then implement `enableInputClicksWhenVisible` method

```
- (BOOL)enableInputClicksWhenVisible
{
    return YES;
}
```

If you are facing issues with this, you can [check this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7456930/1730272)

Comment: Also check this answer for an other example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39385287/1306012

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your original question of whether you can use the Plays Sound 'property' (it's probably not actually a property) to make your buttons play sound is: No. Plays Sound is a 'Trait' that describes the Accessibility of an object (in this case a button) for people who are using VoiceOver (i.e. most likely people who are blind). You can read the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html).

Answer (score 1):

hey you want to play sound on button click event then use bellow code also..

```
-(IBAction)playSound:(id)sender
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"adriantnt_release_click" ofType:@"mp3"]; /// set .mp3 name which you have in project
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate=self;
    [theAudio play];
}
```

and use like bellow..

```
-(IBAction)yourButton_Clicked:(id)sender
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(playSound:) withObject:sender]; 
    //your code  write here
}
```

**Note:** Add `AudioToolbox.framework` Framework And also import 
`#import<AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>` in `.h` file and also add Delegate `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` in `.h` file

i hope this help you...

Comment: Hay currently i am using this method and it is working fine. But i need to shorten my code. Can i use Plays Sound property of UIButton for playing sound?