# Play keyboard click sound in a collection view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I created a subclass of a UICollectionViewController that is used as the custom `inputAccessoryViewController` in a `UITextView`.
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiresponder/1621124-inputaccessoryviewcontroller

I want to play the keyboard click sound when you tap a cell in the collection view using playInputClick.
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidevice/1620050-playinputclick

I cannot figure out how to get this to work in a collection view.  It works for a simple view like this using the `inputAccessoryView` property of a `UITextView` but I'm not sure what view to subclass in the collection view controller hierarchy to get the keyboard click sound to play.

```
@interface KeyboardClickView : UIView <UIInputViewAudioFeedback>
@end

@implementation KeyboardClickView
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self)
    {
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)tap:(id)sender
{
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] playInputClick];
}

- (BOOL)enableInputClicksWhenVisible
{
    return YES;
}
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
    _inputAccessoryView = [[KeyboardClickView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 50)];
    _inputAccessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [[UITextView appearance] setInputAccessoryView:_inputAccessoryView];

    // ...
}
@end
```

I'm also aware that you can play the keyboard click sound using `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1104)` but this doesn't respect the user's settings if they have the keyboard click sounds disabled.

Answer (score 4):

To use the benefits of `playInputClick` in `UIViewController`:

**Dummy input accessory view:**

```
@interface Clicker : UIView <UIInputViewAudioFeedback>

@end

@implementation Clicker

- (BOOL)enableInputClicksWhenVisible
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

**View with input accessory view:**

```
@interface ControllerView : UIView

@end

@implementation ControllerView

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

- (UIView *)inputAccessoryView
{
    return [[Clicker alloc] init];
}

@end
```

**View Controller with custom view:**

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)loadView
{
    self.view = [[ControllerView alloc] init];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.view becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.view resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

> When the responder object becomes the first responder and inputView
> (or inputAccessoryView) is not nil, UIKit animates the input view into
> place below the parent view (or attaches the input accessory view to
> the top of the input view).

There is no visual consequences since the height of `Clicker` view is zero, and conforming to `UIInputViewAudioFeedback` protocol enables `[[UIDevice currentDevice] playInputClick]` functionality within `ViewController`.

Look [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/using_responders_and_the_responder_chain_to_handle_events) for responder chains and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH12) for input accessory views.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm not clear on the use of `Clicker` and why you would want to create this view from another view.  I tried implementing the extra `becomeFirstResponder` and `resignFirstResponder` in my view controller but I'm still not getting a click sound to play.

Comment: Note that `playInputClick` obeys the `Settings / Sounds / Keyboard Clicks` option. Also note that Xcode < 8 Simulator does not reproduces the keyboard clicks.

Comment: @bteapot why is the `Clicker` view necessary? The `ControllerView` could implement `UIInputViewAudioFeedback` protocol and method as well. I tried this but the click sound won't work this way. Can you explain why the `Clicker` view is necessary?

Comment: @BrunoBieri Documentation for `UIInputViewAudioFeedback` protocol states that `enableInputClicksWhenVisible` property is _A property that enables a custom input or keyboard accessory view to play standard keyboard input clicks_. That means that in chain `ViewController.view` -> `ControllerView.inputAccessoryView` -> `Clicker` exactly `Clicker` – as input accessory view of vc's view – must adopt `UIInputViewAudioFeedback` protocol.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, even after so many years ;). I understand that point. I'm just thinking why isn't it possible to implement this protocol on the `ControllerView` itself without needing the `Clicker` view at all? To me the `ControllerView` could be the _custom input view_.

Comment: Yep, it's possible to implement that protocol by any view, and particularly by `ControllerView`. But `UIKit` will notice that only when that view is returned from `inputView` or `inputAccessoryView` of some `UIResponder` subclass ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder)).

Comment: I see. So UIKit only notice that if returned by either `inputView` or `inputAccessoryView`. So still, my question is that it should work that `ControllerView` implement the `UIInputViewAudioFeedback` protocol (enable input clicks) and override it's `inputView` property and returning `self`? Hence, the `Clicker` view wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Nope, won't work. UIKit exclusively manages lifecycle of the view returned from `input...` methods. It adds that view to view hierarchy of the keyboard window when keyboard shows, and removes when keyboard hides. So if you return `self` – your view will be removed from its superview, as minimum, plus any other undefined consequences. It must be two different views – they present on-screen simultaneously, each with it's own parent and frame ([illustration](https://ibb.co/wCYPQY5)).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `UICollectionViewController`, define `KeyboardClickView` as a subclass of `UICollectionView` and place it on a `UIViewController`.

```
@interface KeyboardClickView : UICollectionView <UIInputViewAudioFeedback>

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame collectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)layout {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame collectionViewLayout:layout];

    // existing implementation
```

The new view controller could look something like this:

```
@interface KeyboardClickViewController: UIViewController <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>
@property (nonatomic, strong) KeyboardClickView *clickView;
@end

@implementation KeyboardClickViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.clickView = [[KeyboardClickView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds collectionViewLayout:[UICollectionViewFlowLayout new]];
    self.clickView.delegate = self;
    self.clickView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.clickView];
}

// existing UICollectionViewController logic

@end
```

This allows you to make the call to `playInputClick` from a `UIView` instead of a `UIViewController`.

Comment: I just tried this but it doesn't work for me.  I created a `-playClick` function in my subclassed collection view and then I call this function from the `-didSelectItemAtIndexPath` in the subclassed view controller with collection view delegates.  It's calling the function but no click sound.

Comment: Also just for clarification `playClick` calls `[[UIDevice currentDevice] playInputClick]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working **Swift 4.2** (iOS 11 and 12) version of bteapot's answer.

```
private class ClickerDummyView: UIView, UIInputViewAudioFeedback {
    var enableInputClicksWhenVisible: Bool { return true }
}

private class ClickerControllerView: UIView {
    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        return ClickerDummyView()
    }
}


class ClickingViewController: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        self.view = ClickerControllerView()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        view.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        view.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Now call `UIDevice.current.playInputClick()` from within the `ClickingViewController` class whenever needed and the keyboard click sound will be triggered (with respect to system settings).