# playInputClick not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I was trying some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872239/i-cant-get-my-head-round-voidplayinputclick/7456930#7456930) and checking [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH12-SW4) but I can't get this to work.
Here's my code:

```
@interface AHMSoudView : UIView <UIInputViewAudioFeedback> 
- (void) playClick;
@end

@implementation AHMSoudView
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
     // Initialization code
    }
    return self; 
}



- (BOOL) enableInputClicksWhenVisible {
    return YES; 
} 
- (void) playClick {
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] playInputClick]; 
}
@end
```

In the storyboard I have the view set to my AHMSoundView. In the controller I then have:

```
- (IBAction)keypadTouchDown:(id)sender {
    [((AHMSoudView *)self.view) playClick];
}
```

But nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you connected action in the storyboard from button to keypadTouchDown: method?

Comment: of course, in debug it gets to the playInputClick part but nothing happens...sound is obviously turned on as well...the system keyboard plays the sounds normaly

Comment: well actually I'm using UIButtons placed on the AHMSoundView to update UITextField programmatically...it looks like a phone dialer in iOS7

Comment: it's on screen all the time (as iphone dialer)